# How to add Classpath attribute in manifest.mf when using spring boot maven plugin to build jar

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot maven plugin.I need to add class-path attribute in the manifest.mf file generated.This class-path entry should contain all jar files present in lib folder of the fat jar file created by spring boot.How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is simple solution

Only what you need it is add

> maven-war-plugin

or

> maven-jar-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <mode>development</mode>
                <url>http://sample.com</url>
                <key>value</key>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And put your additional values in manifestEntries .

Regards
Aleksandar